# Query to get one to many records with limit

Tags: sql-server

Table A:

```
ID   NAME
---------
1    ABC
2    XYZ
```

Table B:

```
ID   NAME   AID
----------------
1    ORANGE  1
2    APPLE   1
3    GUAVA   1
4    BANANA  2
5    CHICKO  2
```

**I NEED RESULT SOME THING LIKE
TABLE A ENTRIES WITH ALL ITS VALUES IN TABLE B

```
ID         NAME          BID
---------------------------
1          ABC           1
1          ABC           2
2          XYZ           4
2          XYZ           5
```

Comment: Hint: `JOIN` ... have you tried writing a query for this?

Comment: its was really fast formating

Comment: i need one record from table A with only 2 records in table b

Comment: what DB is it? SQL Server, MySQL?

Comment: What do you mean by `server` tag ?

Comment: you will need a `group by` with limit as you want for each group 2 entities in table b and thereafter can join table a. `Group by with limit` in sql server i guess is done via `partition by(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need an inner join between the two tables:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.ID AS AID, a.NAME, b.ID AS BID,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY b.ID) rn
    FROM tableA a
    INNER JOIN tableB b
        ON a.ID = b.AID
)

SELECT AID, NAME, BID
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Comment: limit is there for One A entry only 2 entries of B

Comment: Check my updated answer.  Your requirement did not come across clearly.

Comment: Looks like its going to work let me try and will update you

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join

```
select a.*, b.id as bid
  from tableA a
  join tableB b on a.id = b.aid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
----------SAMPLE DATA---------
    DECLARE @TABLEA as TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(100))
    DECLARE @TABLEB AS TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(100), AID INT)

    INSERT INTO @TABLEA VALUES (1, 'ABC'),(2,'XYZ')

    INSERT INTO @TABLEB VALUES (1, 'ORANGE', 1),(2, 'APPLE', 1),(3, 'GUAVA', 1),
    (4, 'BANANA', 2),(5, 'CHICKO', 2)

------------SOLUTION-----------------    
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT
        a.ID as AID,
        a.NAME,
        b.ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AID ORDER BY B.ID) as ROWNUMBER
    FROM @TABLEA A
    INNER JOIN @TABLEB B
        ON A.ID = B.AID
        )

    SELECT AID, NAME, ID FROM CTE WHERE ROWNUMBER<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with `row_number()`.  I would tend to do it *before* joining:

```
select a.*, b.id
from tableA a join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by aid order by b.id
      from tableB b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.aid
where b.seqnum <= 2;
```

The optimizer can use an index both for `row_number()` and for the `join`.